# A singular integral on the sphere

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, singular-integrals

Fix $\theta_{0} \in \mathbb{S}^{n}$. I need to identify $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ such that the integral $\;\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{S}^{n}} \frac{d\theta}{|\theta-\theta_{0}|^{\alpha}}$ converges.
My guess is the integral converges iff $\alpha<n$. How do it rigorously ?

Comment: MO copy of the question: [A simple singular integral on the sphere](https://mathoverflow.net/q/288151)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use cylindrical coordinates on the sphere, as it is done for example in [the recent book of Atkinson and Han](https://books.google.es/books?id=SLQxcgt2Xj0C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA7#v=onepage&q&f=false). This allows you to reduce the integral to a one-dimensional one.

**SKETCHY**. Since $\mathbb S^n\subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$, we denote $X=(X_0,X_1\ldots X_n)\in\mathbb R^{n+1}$. Moreover, notice that 
$$|\theta-\theta_0|^2=2-2\theta\cdot \theta_0.$$ 
So, if we assume that $\theta_0=(1,0,\ldots, 0)$, then 
$$|\theta- \theta_0|^\alpha=2^{\frac\alpha 2}(1-X_0)^\frac\alpha 2.$$

Now, as shown in the linked book, the volume element of $\mathbb S^n$ can be expressed in the coordinates $X_0,\ldots X_n$ as follows: 
$$dS^n=(1-X_0^2)^\frac{n-2}{2}dX_0dS^{n-1}, $$
where $dS^{n-1}$ is the volume element of the $n-1$ dimensional sphere (this is why I spoke of "cylindrical" coordinates).

All of this allows us to rewrite our integral as 
$$\int_{\mathbb S^n} \frac{d\theta}{|\theta-\theta_0|^\alpha}=C_\alpha\int_{-1}^1\frac{(1-X_0^2)^\frac{n-2}{2}}{(1-X_0)^\frac\alpha2}\, dX_0=C_\alpha\int_{-1}^1(1-X_0)^\frac{n-\alpha-2}{2}(1+X_0)^\frac{n-2}{2}\,dX_0, $$
which converges if and only if $\alpha<n$, as you conjectured.

Comment: Hi Giuseppe. Thanks a lot for your answer. This exact argument is in Grafakos' "Classical Fourier Analysis", appendix D. I am trying to figure to out for the case $\theta_0 \neq e_i$ .

Comment: Martin. What is wrong with trying to address broader auduence? or is it an opportunity for you to add a comment saying nothing useful.

Comment: The integral is rotation invariant. Use this. (concerning Martin's comment, that's the policy of the site concerning cross-posting. The philosophy is that people needs to know if the question is also posted elsewhere, to avoid doing useless work. Imagine you spend two hours answering and then you discover it is already answered on the other site)

Comment: All right. deleted it  from math overflow. Thanks again Giuseppe.

Comment: @Medo: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16288/8157

Comment: @Medo: If this answer was useful, would you consider [accepting it](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)? Thanks

Comment: Just voted up your answer. Thanks

Comment: @Medo: Thank you for upvoting, but I was talking about **accepting**. If you think an answer is good enough to solve your doubt, you should accept it by clicking on the green tick mark just below the vote arrows. That's a good idea as it marks the question as "answered and accepted" and facilitates the way the system indexes questions. I noticed that you did not accept any answer.

Comment: Yeah. Did not know that. I just accepted your answer.